# cannot knit in r due to "Error: could not find function "%>%" "

Tags: r, knitr

every time I knit in R with the code below,

```
dataset_select %>% 
  group_by(V___DXONSPREPORT) %>%
  summarise(cnt = n()) %>% 
  arrange(desc(cnt))
```

the same message
"Error: could not find function "%>%"  pops up.
I have loaded the librarys dplyr and magrittr.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to include the loading in the document you're knitting with `library`.

Comment: Where did you load dplyr and magrittr. Did you load it in the RMarkdown file itself? Because it needs to be in the document because files are knitted in a separate R session than your main session.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `install.packages('magrittr')` to download the package into R. Then use `library(magrittr)` to use the package that you downloaded. There are also several other packages that use the pipe function `%>%` such as stringr and tidyr.